# Query Parent by Child Relation ParseSwift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, relation

I am looking to query my parent ParseObject by a child relation object. I have a parent named Matches which has a field Relation(Wrestlers). I want to find all matches that a wrestler belongs to. Any assistance is greatly appreciated as I can only find documentation for outdated version of the ParseSwift library and the playground doesn't seem to help as it only uses built in relationships and not custom objects.

This query does not return any results. Wrestler is set to an instance of the ParseObject I want to filter the relation on

```
let query = Match.query("wrestlers" == wrestler).includeAll()
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Is the name of your relation `wrestlers` or `Wrestlers`? Also, can you share how you are creating the `wrestler` var?

Answer (score 0):

The [playgrounds](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/blob/79b760f874c6e4c6c778734f5b85f591862530c1/ParseSwift.playground/Pages/12%20-%20Roles%20and%20Relations.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift#L221-L229) for Roles and Relation states:

> Using this relation, you can create many-to-many relationships with other `ParseObjecs`, similar to `users` and `roles`.

Essentially if you follow the `Roles` example, you should be able to create any relation and query. Specific for your use case (at least using the small amount of code you provided in your question):

```
let match = Match() // Next time, please provide the code for all of your ParseObjects in question.
let matchRelation = match.relation("wrestlers", child: wrestler)
do {
    let wrestlers = try await match.relation.query(wrestler).includeAll().find()
    print("Found related wrestlers: \(wrestlers)")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

In `ParseSwift` 2.4.0+ you can do the following:

```
let matchRelation = match.relation("wrestlers", child: wrestler)
do {
    let wrestlers = try await wrestler.relation.query("wrestlers", parent: match).includeAll().find()
    print("Found related wrestlers: \(wrestlers)")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You can refer to the [Playgrounds in the pending PR](https://github.com/cbaker6/Parse-Swift/blob/20ff549daf645fd475ac83aadf55a3cb8ec29f76/ParseSwift.playground/Pages/12%20-%20Roles%20and%20Relations.xcplaygroundpage/Contents.swift#L246-L310) if more clarity is needed.

> I can only find documentation for outdated version of the ParseSwift library and the playground doesn't seem to help as it only uses built in relationships and not custom objects.

This can't be true as the only documentation for the ParseSwift SDK is the [API documentation](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-Swift/api/) and the [Swift Playgrounds](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-Swift/tree/main/ParseSwift.playground/Pages) which are both up-to-date. If you are referring to the [iOS SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX)'s [documentation](http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#relations) that is a completely different SDK than the ParseSwift SDK. The iOS SDK is an Objective-C SDK that bridges to Swift and the SDK's are not related.